# Is it possible to share printer in guest Windows to host Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, printing, printer, cups

I'm using Linux in company, and cannot set up printer in Linux, so I installed VirtualBox in Linux, and in VirtualBox I installed Windows, I can print in this Windows.

But it is very bother to print this way, I have to copy from linux to windows.

So I'm thinking is it possible to share printer in guest Windows to host Linux?

Comment: How is your printer connected to your machine? Network or USB? Since the printer works with the windows guest your linux host is obviously able to reach the printer? So why can't you set up a printer in Linux? Because you don't know how (which would be a completely different question) or your linux won't allow you for some reason? In essence: if your *guest* can print, you should be able to print on your *host* without trouble - i have only ever heard the problem the other way around, tbh.

Comment: It is a network printer, I have tried setup in Linux, even got the Canon support team to come to my company and they could not solve it...